# Indexing using $ and arguments?

Tags: r

I am very new to R and trying to figure out how to use indexing with $. If I wanted to add an argument, say drop(), how do I use $ with arguments? I tried:

```
subset <- mydata_df$variable1[drop=FALSE]
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `?"[.data.frame"` help page, you'll see that the `$` operator is distinct from the `[` operator and only the latter has the `drop=` argument. Thus the correct syntax for such an extraction is

```
mydata_df[, "variable1", drop=FALSE]
```